# Como fechar uma activity(remover do Foreground)?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Estou com o seguinte codigo na minha classe MainActivity que possui um AlertDialog e o tratamento no método onClick():

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Você deseja sair da aplicação?")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", this)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", this);
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            dialog.cancel();
            finish();
            break;
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Desejo fechar totalmente a activity sem ficar no Foreground, mas a aplicação ainda continua segue a imagem abaixo quando pressiono o botão que esta marcado de vermelho:
[image: Foreground]

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida: Sem ficar no foreground com o Dialog visível? Ou após selecionar a opção de sair? O `finish` ja não faz isso?

Comment: @Wakim nao faz o dialog e fechado mas a activity fica ainda no foreground...

Comment: Chegou a debugar o método `onClick`, ele entra no case do `BUTTON_POSITIVE` e não finaliza? Se for isso, poderia incluir a declaração da `Activity` no `Manifest`?

Comment: ele entra sim no case BUTTON_POSITIVE mas nao finaliza... fica ainda no foregroud.. e justamente isso o problema...

Comment: Poderia incluir a declaração dessa `Activity` no `Manifest`? Poderia verificar também se ocorre algum erro nos métodos `onPause`, `onStop`, e etc? Quando ocorre algum erro nos métodos do ciclo de vida o Android reinicia a `Activity`.

Comment: essa activity ja é a mainActivity ja esta declara... vou dar uma olhada nesses metodos..

Comment: editei o meu post.. peguei a parte do meu projeto que quero testar e fiz outro projeto contendo apenas essa activity.. continua dando a mesma coisa fica no foreground

Comment: Aqui o código funcionou (copiei e colei), gostaria de saber quais atributos definiu na tag `<activity>` para essa `Activity`. Não consigo imaginar qual pode ser o problema.

Comment: vou editar meu post... vou inserir uma imagem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa área que está mostrando na imagem é a [**Recents Screen**](http://developer.android.com/design/handhelds/index.html#home-all-apps-recents). Quando um aplicativo aparece ali, não necessariamente ele está em *foreground*, mas ele foi recentemente usado, possivelmente fechado (como é o seu caso).

É possível controlar a aparição de seu aplicativo na **Recents Screen**, bastando usar o atributo `android:excludeFromRecents` na declaração da `Activity Launcher`. Com isso, seu aplicativo nunca irá aparecer na **Recents Screen**, nem quando for para o plano de fundo pelo botão *Home*.

Para usar basta defini-lo na sua `Activity`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Para mais detalhes, basta acessar a [documentação desse atributo](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude).

Comment: era exatamente isso.. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

neste código a activity sera fechada assim que você sair dela ou abrir outra activity

**Sobrescrever o método onPause() da Activity**

```
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: nao funciona pois.. o dialogo e executado quando a activity e aberta..  ou seja o dialog permanece e activity e fechada... eu so quero fechar somente quando eu aperta pra sair..

Comment: não tem nada haver com que eu preciso no momento pra resolução do problema...